# basic query statement fails to execute

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query="INSERT INTO ".$table_name." VALUES ('$rowNum','$something',$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'], '$somethingelse')";
```

The error produced is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in line 15
```

I have a problem with that query but I don't know where the mistakes are. Anyone sees the light please shed it on me. Thank you for your spot.

EDIT:
The query to create my table is

```
$query="CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." (id int not null auto_increment, something varchar(128), post_date varchar(32), edit_date varchar(32), somethingelse text)";
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo out the query so you can see what is being asked. Then test it by placing the query into your preferred database amin program like phpmyadmin or workbench etc and test the query in there to see if it runs as a static request, this should also yield more of an error, possibly,

Comment: I get the impression that [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would have a field day here.

Comment: It looks like you are using multiple tables as a substitute for having an extra column in an existing table. This is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I find this syntax easier to manage and debug for anything but the most basic of parameter replacement into strings:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');", $table_name,                      
                  $rowNum, $something, $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'],
                  $somethingelse)
```

N.B. You can also use printf in place of sprintf with the same structure to output the same string just like a print or echo statement.

A couple of other suggestions too:

1. Use PDO to simplify and abstract the database operations as well as making it easier to secure all of the statements with bound parameters in prepared statements.
2. Instead of using $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] perhaps some default 'now()' date fields and triggers for mod_dates on the database would be more reliable and maintainable. (although I don't have full context to know whether you are explicitly inserting the server time for another reason which can't be handled by timestamping handled by the DB)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$query="INSERT INTO ".$table_name." VALUES ('$rowNum','$something',".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'].",". $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']", '$somethingelse')";
```

EDIT - the problem was with  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` which doesn't get interpreted by php as `$sometext` and so you have to concatenate it

Comment: What have you changed? Spot the difference answers aren't as helpful as they could be.

Comment: @Quentin sorry, i just concatenated `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`, because it's not converted by php and  `'` broke your query

Comment: @Quentin php does variable interpolation with variables, for associative arrays you could do $_SERVER[REQUEST_TIME] (without the `'`) but you get a notice

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query="INSERT INTO ".$table_name." VALUES ('$rowNum','$something','".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']."','". $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']."', '$somethingelse')";
```

Array values are should not be in single or double quotes.